# State is not updating from a function when the components are inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

Changing state from other components in this case (`Dominator`) is working but when I put those components inside an array and do the same thing the `updateCounter` function is getting called but it's not updating the `counter` state.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Dominator from "./dominator";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  const updateCounter = () => {
    console.log("counter lookup: ", counter);
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };
  const [dominators, setDominators] = useState([
    <Dominator key={0} updateCounter={updateCounter} />
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("counter has changed:", counter)
  }, [counter])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {dominators.map((item) => {
        return item;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is stale state enclosures in the `updateCounter` callback. Each mapped element is receiving a callback with the same value of `counter` to update from.

Storing instantiated React components in state is also anti-pattern and doesn't help the stale state enclosures. You should store the data only and render the derived JSX from the data.

## Solution

Use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state instead of the state the callback/state update was enclosed in.

Store only the data in the `dominators` state and map it to the `Dominator` component.

```
export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

  const updateCounter = () => {
    setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
  };

  const [dominators, setDominators] = useState([0]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("counter has changed:", counter);
  }, [counter]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {dominators.map((item) => (
        <Dominator key={item} updateCounter={updateCounter} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: now the counter state is updating but inside the updateCounter , updated counter state is not getting shown . Any idea ?

Comment: @sabbir_rifat Can you clarify what you mean by "updated counter state is not getting shown"?

Comment: no worries, after you updated the solution now it's working perfectly. Thank you so much, brother. You saved my day